# assistance with parsing JSON results

Tags: php, json

Trying to wrap my head around pulling data from a JSON API Call.

Here's the provided data when I fetch the url:

```
{
  "status":200,
  "count":1,
  "data": [
    {
      "image":"http:\/\/www.airport-data.com\/images\/aircraft\/thumbnails\/001\/099\/001099109.jpg",
      "link":"http:\/\/www.airport-data.com\/aircraft\/photo\/001099109.html",
      "photographer":"Ray Barber"
    }
  ]
}
```

I just need to fetch the 'image' and 'link' value to generate a thumbnail.

My current PHP:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://www.airport-data.com/api/ac_thumb.json?m=40073D&n=1');
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);

$thumbnail = $parsed_json->data->image;
$thumbnaillink = $parsed_json->data->link;
echo $thumbnail;
echo $json_string;
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out the proper syntax for $thumbnail and $thumbnaillink.

I've tried a few different variations of examples I've found here and elsewhere online but I can never get a value returned to them.

My first time digging into this stuff so appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json object that holds the "image" and "link" properties is inside an **array**.

In order to get "image" and "link" in your example, you'd have to access the first element of the "data" array like this:

```
$thumbnail = $parsed_json->data[0]->image;
$thumbnaillink = $parsed_json->data[0]->link;
```

Comment: Right.  Basically the json_decode function returns a "Standard Object" but it doesn't (as you might reasonably expect) do this recursively.  So here, "data" is just an array that your object has.  If you like, you can make it consistently an associative array by setting the second argument of json_decode to true:  json_decode($json_string, true)